# Not able to read file using C

Tags: c

Here is the code I have:

```
 #include<stdio.h>
 #include<stdlib.h>
void main()
{
 int n,i,a[40];
 char file_name[100];
 FILE *file;
 printf("enter the file name\n");
     scanf("%s",&file_name);
 printf("enter the size\n");
 scanf("%d",&n);

 if((file=fopen(file_name,"rb"))==NULL)
 {
  printf("cant open a file\n");
  return;
 }
 fread(a,sizeof(int),n,file);
 for(i=0;i<n;i++)
 {
  printf("%s",a[i]);
 }
}
```

Comment: Format your code please: select it and click the '{}' button.

Comment: What exactly is your problem/question? (What error are you getting?)

Comment: In future please take the time to format the code in your question appropriately (using the "{}" editor control).

Comment: Why `printf("%s",a[i]);`? Shouldn't it be `printf("%d",a[i]);` since a[i] is an int?

Comment: What if you enter a filename over 100 characters?

Comment: You did not say how it is failing, or give any of the nature of the file you are attempting to read.  Your code would be correct if the file you are reading is raw binary data written on the same machine using the fwrite function.  Reading raw binary data is full of nasty gotcha's like word endianness conversions, struct packing etc.  --  If you are trying to read a text file use fscanf or similar functions.

Answer (score 7):

Change:

```
 scanf("%s",&file_name);
```

to:

```
 scanf("%s", file_name);
```

You also need to change:

```
 printf("%s",a[i]);
```

to:

```
 printf("%d", a[i]);
```

(and while you're at it, change `void main` to `int main`).

Comment: Beaten for a matter of seconds! ;)

Comment: Warning: control reaches end of non-void function.

Comment: @Graham Lee: indeed - I was holding off on the warnings and just focussing on the actual bugs, but as you say it needs a `return` statement.

Answer (score 1):

```
scanf("%s",&file_name);
```

you don't have to pass a pointer to `file_name` since it's already a pointer. Change this line to:

```
scanf("%s", file_name);
```